# select between multiple values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm working with PHP and AJAX in order to code a very simple CRUD and I would like to show a form and three buttons: Grabar, Modificar and Eliminar, my problem is that I cannot determine in code which action to perform depending on the button clicked, for example: if the customer clicks the Grabar button it has to redirection to registro.php, if the customer clicks the modificar button it has to redirections to modificar.php and the same logic for the Eliminar button(redirects to eliminar.php).

How can I accomplish that in javascript? so far I have this:

```
function enviarDatosEmpleado(){

  //div donde se mostrará lo resultados
  divResultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
  //recogemos los valores de los inputs
  nom=document.nuevo_empleado.nombre.value;
  ape=document.nuevo_empleado.apellido.value;
  web=document.nuevo_empleado.web.value;
  valor=document.nuevo_empleado.Submit.value;

  alert(valor);
}
  /* 
  ajax=objetoAjax();

  ajax.open("POST", "registro.php",true); */
```

and my form is:

```
<form name="nuevo_empleado" action="" onsubmit="enviarDatosEmpleado(); return false">
            <h2>Nuevo empleado</h2>
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nombres</td><td><label><input name="nombre" type="text" /></label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Apellido</td><td><label><input type="text" name="apellido"></label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Web</td><td><label><input name="web" type="text" /></label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td><td><label><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Grabar" /></label></td>
                    <td><label><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Modificar" /></label></td>
                    <td><label><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Eliminar" /></label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
        </form>
```

Could you also please help me with the if statement please?

Comment: Ok, so if you want to use ajax, don't use the form submit action. You don't even need a form. Just add `click` event handlers to your buttons, and in each handler, perform the ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out.

```
  document.getElementsByName('nuevo_empleado')[0].onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var redirectHash = {
        grabar: 'registro.php',
        modificar: 'modificar.php',
        eliminar: 'eliminar.php'
    };

    if (e.target.type === 'submit') {
        window.location.href = redirectHash[e.target.value.toLowerCase()]; 
    }
  };
```

**JSBin Demo: http://jsbin.com/kefapofato/1/edit?html,js,output**

Answer (score 0):

Modify the action property on the form.

```
switch (valor) {
  case 'Grabar':
    document.nuevo_empleado.action = 'registro.php';
    break;
  case 'Modificar':
    document.nuevo_empleado.action = 'modificar.php';
    break;
  case 'Eliminar':
    document.nuevo_empleado.action  = 'eliminar.php';
    break;
}
```

This isn't really the "right" way to do what you want, though. It's much cleaner if you install separate handlers for each button's click event, so that *different* handlers are invoked for each one.

```
<form ...>
  ...
  <input type='submit' value='Grabar' onclick='this.form.action = "registro.php";'>
  <input type='submit' value='Modificar' onclick='this.form.action = "modificar.php";'>
  ...
</form>
```

To use the commented-out Javascript you have at the bottom of the sample code, you have to do two things. First, you have modify your event handler to accept an `event` parameter. You need this parameter to prevent the browser from submitting the form itself.

Then, to have different behavior depending on the selected button, you can use something like the `switch` button in my first example.

```
function enviarDatosEmpleado(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // this stops the browser from submitting the form
  ...
  var ajax = objectoAjax();
  switch (valor) {
    case 'Grabar':
      ajax.open('POST', 'registro.php', true);
      break;
    case 'Modificar:
      ajax.open('POST', 'modficar.php', true);
      break;
    case 'Eliminar:
      ajax.open('POST', 'eliminar.php', true);
      break;
  }
```

Comment: hello and thanks for the answer... what I want is that depending on the buttom clicked change the url in ajax.open("POST", "registro.php",true); in this order: click in submit button then it goes to ajax.open("POST", "registro.php",true); click in button modificar then it goes to ajax.open("POST", "modificar.php",true); and so that it goes for eliminar...I tried the swith you posted but didn't work.